# Datamapper Ruby How to add Hook Method

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I have a simple association of header and item (1 : 1). when I say

```
class Header 
include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :somedata
  has 1, :item
end

class Item
include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  attr_accessor: full_name, String
  belongs_to :user
end
Header.get(1).item
```

I would like to have a hook for item for doing some translation(say some initialization for full_name~updating the attr_accessor fields). This has to be generalized as I don't want do a before method  item on the header ..but hook method the item model. so that however the item is called the translation/initialization happens.

How can this be done?

Comment: So when you call `.item`, which has been generated with `attr_accessor`, you want to apply a transformation to the data?

Comment: You want the data to exist in the ruby object as a method. Do you also want the data to exist in the DB connected to that model or is there another datastore?

Comment: no it is just a attr_accessor meaning it is just variable which just not exist in database but only to hold data for the model and just to call as a method to assign and retreive..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it myself. wanted to update in case it might be useful other people. just need define a method for that attribute.

```
def full_name
  "Mr"+full_name
end
```